# PNG area drawn on the canvas using fabric.js is cut off

Tags: javascript

I'm using fabric.js to create something like an acrylic keychain preview simulator.
As you can see in the screenshot, the blurred part is cut off.
I think it's probably cut off to fit the PNG display area...
Is there any way to improve this?

[image]

```
<script>
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('design-canvas');

    // image manage
    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

    function handleImage(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                var stickerCanvas = stickerEffect(img, 12);
                var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(stickerCanvas, {
                    scaleX: 0.25,
                    scaleY: 0.25,
                });
                imgInstance.setControlsVisibility({
                    mt: false, // middle top
                    mb: false, // middle bottom
                    ml: false, // middle left
                    mr: false, // middle right
                    bl: false, // bottom left
                    //br: false,    // bottom right
                    tl: false, // top left
                    tr: false, // top right
                    mtr: false, // middle top rotete

                });

                canvas.add(imgInstance);

                // 画像のdata URLを取得する
                var imgData = imgInstance.toDataURL();

                // ダウンロードボタンを表示する
                var dlLink = document.createElement('a');
                dlLink.href = imgData;
                dlLink.download = 'download.png';
                dlLink.innerText = 'ダウンロード';
                document.getElementById('result').appendChild(dlLink);
                // 画像を削除する関数
                function deleteImage() {
                    canvas.remove(imgInstance);
                }
                var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
                deleteButton.innerHTML = '削除';
                deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deleteImage);

                document.getElementById('result2').appendChild(deleteButton);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        rect.set('selectable', false); // make object unselectable
    }

    function stickerEffect(img, grow) {
        var canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
        var canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
        var canvas3 = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");
        canvas1.width = canvas2.width = canvas3.width = img.width + grow * 2;
        canvas1.height = canvas2.height = canvas3.height = img.height + grow * 2;
        ctx1.drawImage(img, grow, grow);
        ctx2.shadowColor = 'white';
        ctx2.shadowBlur = 8;
        for (var i = 0; i < grow; i++) {
            ctx2.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0);
            ctx1.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0);
        }
        ctx2.shadowColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
        ctx2.shadowBlur = 1;
        ctx2.drawImage(img, grow, grow);
        ctx3.shadowColor = 'white';
        ctx3.shadowBlur = '0';
        for (var i = 0; i < grow; i++) {
            ctx3.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0);
            ctx2.drawImage(canvas3, 0, 0);
        }
        ctx3.shadowColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
        ctx3.drawImage(img, grow, grow);
        return canvas3;
    }
</script>
```

Originally, I wanted to be able to convert PNG to SVG and preview it by combining the SVG and the path of the hole through which the keychain is passed, so I tried combining fabric.js and imagetracer.js. , it was too difficult for beginners.

I thought I could add padding to the Fabric.js property to make it wider, but all I did was make the handle area wider.

[image]

```
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(stickerCanvas, {
                    scaleX: 0.25,
                    scaleY: 0.25,
                    padding: 25,
                });
```